# Django accessing values returned in Array with POST

Tags: django, post

I'm trying to return form data as an array, my html looks like this :

```
 {% for f in factures %}
            <tbody>
                <td>{{ f.numero }}</td>
                <td>{{ f.date}}</td>
                <td>{{ f.sommeRestante }}</td>
                <td><input type="number" name="valeur[]" value=0></td>
            </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
```

in my view when i execute `print(request.POST)` i get :

`<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken':[...], 'valeur[]': ['100', '0']}>`

how can i access the values '100' and '0'?

i tried `request.POST['valeur[]'][0]` but it returns `0` (it's returning the default value set inside html)

**EDIT :**
i'm not doing much in my view :

```py
def sauv_reg(request, pk):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST['valeur[]'][0])
        redirect("home")
```

**Edit 2:**

`print(request.POST['valeur[]'])` is returning the second index in my POST so 0

Comment: can you share views.py?

Comment: Do `print(request.POST['valeur[]'])`…!?

Comment: @deceze it doesn't return the array it returns a value of 0

Comment: See the documentation of [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) and/or the above duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

In the view you have to access the cleaned_data when the form is correct, for example:

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = YourForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            valeur = form.cleaned_data['valeur[]']
...
```

For this you need to create a django form, I recommend it for best practices and clarity.

Comment: using a form will cause problems bacause i will get multiple inputs with the same name, as for formsets well i can't find how to display them one by one

Comment: well so why not try: print(request.POST['valeur[]']). and see what is returning?

Comment: i replied to a comment above suggesting this, it doesn't return the array, but a value 0 instead (which is the value of the 2nd index)

Comment: Can you try to print: request.body and show me the result please?